# How do I expose a SOAP endpoint using the WCF Starter Kit?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, rest, soap

I am new to WCF so please bear with me.

Using the latest version of the WCF REST Starter kit, I created a web service that is being called by an Android application. The RESTful endpoint is working fine but I would like to create a SOAP endpoint so that a .NET client will be able to use it and generate all the necessary classes.

I am still using the default configuration file and I am a little confused about what I need to do to it.

Here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I think I need to add the following somewhere into the config file but I am unsure where it belongs or if I am on the right path.

```
<endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="Service1"/>
<endpoint name="soap" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Service1"/>
```

I only have one class and that is Service1.cs. I have tried to make some changes but I have had no success.

I would like to know what I have to add and an explanation of why it's needed would be wonderful.

-- Update --

After I inserted the services tag, I was having trouble getting the 'Add Service Reference' feature to work in visual studio. I found out that 'HttpGetEnabled' needs to be true, so it would publish the service metadata to http.

I added this and it seems like its working.

```
<behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
              </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
```

If I add more services, do I have to create two more endpoints for that service too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expose additional endpoints on your service, you need to add those to the `<service name="....">` tag in your config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="NameSpace.ServiceClassName>
       <endpoint name="rest" 
                 address=""
                 binding="webHttpBinding"
                 contract="IService1" />
       <endpoint name="soap" 
                 address="soap"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 contract="IService1" />
       <endpoint name="mex" 
                 address="mex"
                 binding="mexHttpBinding"
                 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

You're obviously using the WCF 4 standard endpoints being exposed - if you want to change that, you will need to explicitly spell out all your config you need.

Now, your service (as implemented in `ServiceClassName` in the `NameSpace` namespace) will have three endpoints:

- the base address of your *.svc file will be the REST endpoint using `webHttpBinding`
- the `(service.svc)/soap` address will be the same contract (same service methods), but using the SOAP-based `basicHttpBinding`
- the `(service.svc)/mex` address will have the service metadata for the SOAP clients