# WCF 4.0 Add WebHttpBinding Endpoint by Default

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-binding

Is there a way to do this globally, automatically for all my WCF services via configuration in WCF 4.0?

That is, I know WCF 4.0 exposes new configuration techniques that applies certain behaviors by default to all hosted endpoints, and that you don't need to explicitly specify individual  endpoints by config anymore...but can I do something in the config that says to automatically host all services with both a BasicHttpBinding and a WebHttpBinding (using a /web relative address for the WebHttpBinding)? Or do I still need to use a custom ServiceHostFactory for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Developer's Introduction to WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) for lots of interesting stuff in WCF 4.

One of the new features is called **default protocol mapping**, and this combined with the default endpoints provided by WCF 4 might solve your problem.

Default endpoints means that WCF 4 will provide one endpoint for each contract your service class implements (typically only 1), and for each base address defined in your config (or code for the `ServiceHost`).

In order to make sure a `http://` endpoint gets exposed automagically with the `webHttpBinding`, you also need to override the system default (which is `basicHttpBinding`) - which you can do thanks to the protocol mappings.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way I can tell it to use both webHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding (perhaps with a relative url of /web for the webHttpBinding)?

Comment: @JeffN825: no, you cannot have both HTTP-based bindings automatically - if you need this, you have to define the endpoints and their bindings explicitly, in code or config. You can only define one default binding per "scheme" (http, net.tcp, etc.) See my answer to this other SO question about this very topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704829/how-do-i-expose-a-soap-endpoint-using-the-wcf-starter-kit/4704847#4704847

Comment: Btw. If you use WebServiceHost, webHttpBinding will be used as default without any configuration.